# Is this documentation comment correct?

Tags: c++, comments, code-documentation

I want to make C++ equivalent of JavaDoc in my header file.
I have got function members that look like :

```
Grid(int, int);

void displayCells(void) const;

bool isCellInGrid(int, int) const;
```

So what will be correct comment if I do not put names of attributes in .h file?

```
/**
 * Grid constructor
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
Grid(int, int);

/**
 * Function that displays grid on std output
 */
void displayCells(void) const;

/**
 * Tells if cell is in grid
 * @param cell x
 * @param cell y
 * @return true if is in the grid, otherwise false
 */
bool isCellInGrid(int, int) const;
```

Comment: I am just confused if I should put @param comments if I do not name arguments

Comment: Is it a doxygen question?

Comment: Do not use comments when they are not needed. For example, instead of long description of `Grid(int, int)` change the declaration to `Grid(int width, int height);`. Now you need no comments - It is clear it is a constructor, and parameters are self-explained. If you need to comment, comment **how**, not **what**. For example, explain how `width` and `height` are used in the constructed grid.

Comment: No it is not doxygen question. I just want to comment my uni project, and I do not generate any documentation. I just want to make code easier to understand

Comment: `bool isCellInGrid(int, int) const;` looks like a useless comment. it makes it harder to read your header as it increases the noise to signal ratio.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but as a side note: eww... Don't hide the param names in the comments, that will break most autocomplete tools.  Always spell out the function signature: "bool isCellInGrid(int x, int y) const;".